# Can geometric programming be considered as a special case of second order cone programming?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

From the [Mosek cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/latest/toolbox/tutorial-gp-shared.html), it is clear that by using the log-sum-exp transformation and some extra variable $u_k$, a geometric programing problem can be transform into a exponential cone presentation.

Therefore, my question is "Can geometric programming be considered as a special case of second order cone programming ?"

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Not second order cone, but exponential cone. Otherwise yes, you can think that, although "reduces to" would perhaps fit better than in this context than "a special case of". After all you have to do some preprocessing to the geometric problem to get an exponential cone problem.

Comment: Wow this is very insightful ! Does that mean geometric programming problem can be solved in polynomial time ?